# obtener ítem de un array en php

Tags: php, json, array

lo que sucede es que tengo un array que me devuelve una api, lo que necesito es obtener el ítem de ese array y guardarlo en una variable el problema que me pasa es que me guarda en la variable el item pero asi: string(685)"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9" y lo que busco es solo  "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9"

este es el codigo que estoy implementado

```
 $array2 = json_decode($result, true);
  $array3  = $array2 ['token'];
```

este es el array

```
{"token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9"}
```

lo que busco es guardar en una variable "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debería ser algo similar a lo siguiente.

```
$json = '{"token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9"}';
$array = json_decode($json, true);

echo $token = $array['token'];
```

Saludos.

Comment: gracias me sirvió mucho